# double colon :: java 8 how does the following even work

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference

I came across the following code:

```
List<Fields> invFieldsLst = new ArrayList<>();
InvListener listener = invFieldsLst::add;
```

The following interface:

```
public interface InvListener {

  void test(Fields fields);

}
```

How does the double :: even work?
I just dont understand how thats working..

Comment: You do know that this is known as a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html), right?

Comment: i undertsand thats a method reference, but how is it being assigned to the interface of a different type...

Comment: Wouldn't you use `InvListener::test` since the method's name is `test`?

Comment: got it.. basically its eqv too  (i) -> { invFieldsLst.add(i); }; its an impl for that method...

Answer (score -1):

got it.. basically its eqv too (i) -> { invFieldsLst.add(i); }; its an impl for that method